# set scroll bar to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroll bar inside a div called "smsBlk". I would like to move this scroll bar to a particular element ("msgUnread") which is a child element of "smsBlk".  All the child elements will be rendered dynamically.

```
<div id="smsBlk" class="" style="height: calc(100vh - 320px);overflow-y: scroll;margin-bottom: 10px;padding: 20px;width:100%;background: #ecf0f1;">
<div class="msg"></div>
<div class="msg"></div>
<div class="msg"></div>
<div id="msgUnread" class="msg"></div>
<div class="msg"></div>
<div class="msg"></div>
</div>
```

Tried using offSet().Top. But,no luck. offSet().Top of msgUnread element was returning negative value if we scroll to bottom. This scrollbar is not for entire page. Can any one please help me to achieve the functionality?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek yes, tried element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "end"}); .Moves the scroll bar but not upto the target div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
document.getElementById('msgUnread').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

**Note**: This smooth scrolling behavior will work fine in chrome, but I'm not sure with other browsers

Comment: Nope, not working. It is showing small movement of scrollbar.